# Python file wont write blank new line

Tags: python, file-writing, f-string

I'm making these report files and am trying to append a blank line in between each cycle of my loop, just to help with readability.

Usually, I can just open the file and f.write('\n') to do this - for whatever reason now when I view this file it will not work. I have a few conditions so I've tried adding '\n' to the end of my output strings. Some examples below. Any ideas?? I've tried in write mode too and it doesn't work.

Fails

```
            #enter MSI status into output csv
            with open(f'{date}-output.csv', 'a') as f:
                #workaround f strings with \n
                newline= '\n'
                f.write(f'MSI status for {sample_id},{msi_result}{newline}')
```

Fails

```
            #enter MSI status into output csv
            with open(f'{date}-output.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(f'MSI status for {sample_id},{msi_result}\n')
```

Fails

```
            #enter MSI status into output csv
            with open(f'{date}-output.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(f'MSI status for {sample_id},{msi_result}')
                f.write('\n')
```

I've even got one that fails on my except, where I'm just doing

```
            #insert new line on either success or failure
            with open(f'{date}-output.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the {sample_id} and {msi_result} get written in fine, I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: Did you know you can [edit] your question to add more information? Comments are to ask for clarifications, not for supplemental information. Just put it into your question. Thanks.

Comment: A single newline character isn't going to produce a blank line, you'd need two of them in a row to do that.

Comment: `write` doesn't add a new line, so if you want two you need to write two `newline = '\n'*2`

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion might be because `print()` and `write()` behave differently.

`print()` automatically adds a newline at the end of the text, but `write()` does not.

If you want to write a line of text followed by a blank line, you need two newlines:

```
f.write('Hello I am glad to meet you.  A blank line is next.\n')
f.write('\n')
```

Of course you can also just put two newline characters into a single message:

```
f.write('Hello\n\n')
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
f.write("\n\r")
```

it should work